# Directive cannot be used as an entry component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I am doing an Angular 2 demo with injection and get an error that my CustomDirective can't be used as an entry element.

So, my NgModule

```
    import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import AppComponent from  './app.component';
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}



const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

AppComponent:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TIMER_DIRECTIVES} from './timer/timer';
import {TASK_DIRECTIVES} from './tasks/tasks';
import {SHARED_PROVIDERS} from './shared/shared';


@Component({
    selector: 'tomato-app',
    entryComponents: [TIMER_DIRECTIVES,TASK_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [SHARED_PROVIDERS],
    template: `
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <strong class="navbar-brand">Tomato App</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <tomato-timer-widget></tomato-timer-widget>
        <tomato-tasks></tomato-tasks>`
})
export default class AppComponent{}
```

And the custom directive itself:

```
import {Task} from '../shared/shared'
import {Input, HostListener, Directive} from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[task]'
})
export default class TaskTooltipDirective {
    private defaultTooltipText: string;
    @Input() task: Task;
    @Input() taskTooltip: any;

    @HostListener('mouseover')
    onMouseOver() {
        if (!this.defaultTooltipText && this.taskTooltip) {
            this.defaultTooltipText = this.taskTooltip.innerText;
        }
        this.taskTooltip.innerText = this.task.name;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseout')
    onMouseOut() {
        if (this.taskTooltip) {
            this.taskTooltip.innerText = this.defaultTooltipText;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am using entryComponents in AppComponent incorrectly. How do I need to link a custom directive?

Comment: In the root NgModule, try adding `entryComponents: [AppComponent]`. 
The docs say it's unnecessary to add AppComponent to entryComponents but it doesn't hurt your code just extra redundancy

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: Unfortunately nope

Answer (score 4):

`entryComponents`: list of components that are dynamically inserted into the view of this component

`How do I need to link a custom directive?`
Put your all directive, pipe, component in `declarations` array at `NgModule` level:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, TIMER_DIRECTIVES, TASK_DIRECTIVES],
    bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

note that, if you declare `provider` at `Component` level:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tomato-app',
    providers: [SHARED_PROVIDERS],
    //...
})
```

it will create new instance for all instances of this component. in other word, if you have 2 different Component, with 2 declare `providers: [SHARED_PROVIDERS]`, then the `SHARED_PROVIDERS` of 2 component are different. you need declare in NgModule level to use same instance in all component of this NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, TIMER_DIRECTIVES, TASK_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [SHARED_PROVIDERS],
    entryComponents: [TIMER_DIRECTIVES, TASK_DIRECTIVES],
    bootstrap:[AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Comment: Still no luck with it

Comment: I've updated answer, please add one more array `entryComponents` to NgModule